# Access external USB flash drive with OTG adapter

Tags: android, storage

In an application I am developing, I need to perform read/write operations to a USB flash drive connected to my tablet using a USB OTG adapter. The application will to be used internally, so I know that it will always run on a rooted Motorola Xoom WiFi running a distribution of 4.2.2. I've looked at the USB Host classes in the Android API, and those seem to be what I need to access external storage. However, there doesn't appear to be any clean interface to/from external devices (such as like `java.io.File`). Is there an easy way to perform file operations on an external USB drive, or am I going to have to deal with bytestreams and the like from the Usb Host classes?